# Execute Script in Chrome Extension Page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension and I want to `executeScript` in the extension page such as `chrome-extension://URL`. When I try to run the script in the extension page with:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript( { code: `myFunc(${myVariable})` } );
```

in the extension page, I am getting the following error:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access contents of url "chrome-extension://mcbaafjcjmpmjjbdpadcpenjmnkaneel/test.html". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.
```

It looks like I cannot request permission for chrome-extension pages. Is there any workaround for this issue?

Note: I have tried to run the same command from the `background.js` file but I am getting the same error.

Thanks

Comment: Well, as the error suggests, you probably need to update the manifest file. Try something like including `<all_urls>` in `permissions` property and see if it works, then make the permission more specific.

Comment: If the page doesn't belong to your extension you can't run code there unles you start Chrome with a special command line switch. If this is your own page, you don't need executeScript because you can send a message to the page.

Comment: You cannot run a script in other extension's pages. If you want to run it in your own extension page, just include it with a simple `<script>` tag.